# Is $i$ an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5},w)$ where $w=e^{2πi/3}$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am trying to check if $i$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5},w)$ where $w=e^{2πi/3}$. How can I check if this is the case? Would it be correct to express my field as $a\mathbb(\sqrt[4]{5}) + b (-1/2 + i (\sqrt{3}/2))$ for rationals $a$ and $b$ and show that no combination of these gives me the element $i$?

Comment: No, the field elements are sums of terms of the form $$a_{ij}(\sqrt[4]5)^iw^j$$ where $i=0,1,2,3$ and $j=0,1$ and the $a_{ij}$ are rational. It needs to be a field, so closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: You can show that the imaginary part of any field element are of the form $\sqrt{3}p(\sqrt[4]5),$ where $p(x)$ is some rational polynomial. If you don't have any general tools, that is the way I'd go - show not only that $i$ not in the field, but that no field element has imaginary component $1.$

Comment: This amounts to showing that $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}).$

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the field are of the form:

$$\alpha=a_{00}+a_{01}w+a_{10}\sqrt[4]5+a_{11}\sqrt[4]5w+a_{20}\sqrt[4]{5^2}+a_{21}\sqrt[4]{5^2}w+a_{30}\sqrt[4]{5^3}+a_{31}\sqrt[4]{5^3}w$$
where the $a_{ij}$ are rational numbers.

The imaginary component of this is:

$$\operatorname{Im}\alpha =\frac{\sqrt3}2\left(a_{01}+a_{11}\sqrt[4]5+a_{21}\sqrt[4]{5^2}+a_{31}\sqrt[4]{5^3}\right)$$

If $\operatorname{Im}\alpha =1,$ then you get, by multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{3}:$

$$\sqrt{3}=\frac32\left(a_{01}+a_{11}\sqrt[4]5+a_{12}\sqrt[4]{5^2}+a_{13}\sqrt[4]{5^3}\right)\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5).$$

So if you can show $\sqrt 3\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5),$ you will have shown $i$ can't be in your field.

---

You can prove the other way - if $z$ is a real number and $w$ is the value in the original problem, then $\mathbb Q(z,w)$ contains $i$ if and only if $\sqrt3\in\mathbb Q(z).$

Essentially, if $K$ is a complex field, $K(w)$ can be seen to be equivalent to $K(i\sqrt 3).$ If $K$ is a real field, then the imaginary component of $K(w)$ are all of the form $a\sqrt 3$ for $a\in K.$

In this question $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5).$

Comment: I understand, thank you!